# In AWS CloudFormation stack status is changing to ROLLBACK_COMPLETE from CREATE_IN_PROGRESS while creating new stack using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, esp8266, aws-iot-core, mongoose-os

I am on the AWS educate account and closely following this tutorial
https://github.com/mongoose-os-apps/aws-iot-button

> This is an Internet Button reference project: when a button on the device is pressed, a cloud backend gets a notification and performs an action. In this particular case, AWS Lambda function sends an email to the specific email address.

For that I require a stack.
But stack status is changing to ROLLBACK_COMPLETE from CREATE_IN_PROGRESS while creating new stack using aws cli.

I tried deleting and redoing the stack from cli making the necessary changes

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name my-internet-button --parameters ParameterKey=TopicName,ParameterValue=$DEVICE_ID/button_pressed ParameterKey=SubscriptionEmail,ParameterValue=$MY_EMAIL --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --template-body file://aws_button_template.json
```

Still the status gets down to ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

Here is a picture of my stack event
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The reason of ROLLBACK_COMPLETE is the stack failed to create 1 or more resources. To troubleshoot, open your stack on web console --> Events --> check the first CREATE_FAILED resource (from the bottom) and the Status reason.

Comment: As the events show there was a  1. failed attempt to create: [myLambda] and  2. the runtime parameter of nodejs4.3 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. Recommended to use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can find root-cause i.e. by checking  status reason for status CREATE_FAILED under list of events.

1. `aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name my-internet-button --output json`

OR

2. Check more events under events tab of AWS web-console.

Comment: As the events show there was a  1. failed attempt to create: [myLambda] and  2. the runtime parameter of nodejs4.3 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. Recommended to use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudFormation stack rolls back on failure, so need to know the reason on events tab, if you wish to disable rollback on failure, you can check the following link:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-prevent-rollback-failure/

Comment: As the events show there was a  1. failed attempt to create: [myLambda] and  2. the runtime parameter of nodejs4.3 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. Recommended to use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions.

Comment: On updating to nodejs12.20.0 still facing the same issue of stack rollback.